# What is a good metric for agreement in this problem?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, agreement-statistics

Suppose I have a dataset that needs annotations.
I have about $5000$ total $x$ values, and annotations by humans are needed to create $y$ values.
$y$ takes a value in $\{0, 1\}$. For example, consider a cat images detection dataset. You have a list of photos (the $x$ values), and annotators will indicate 0 if not a cat image and 1 if it is (the $y$ values).

Multiple people are annotating all of the dataset independently. I need a metric of how much they agree.

The simplest metric is this:  $$ score = 1 - \dfrac{ \#  \text{ of disagreements }}{\text{total}} $$

But the problem is, the number of 1s is very low compared to total, say about
100. If I have 3 annotators, even if all disagree, the score will be $300/5000=94\%$ which is a very high score despite massive disagreement.

OTOH if I remove all where there's only $0$s,  I'm discarding all agreements as well.

What is a good metric here?

Comment: Your first metric doesn't take into account the number of annotators. You use a total of $5000$, even though there are three annotators, which means more annotators would give you more $1$s, even though it's the same data set. I would recommend replacing the number of disagreements in the numerator by number of disagreements divided by number of annotators (which is just avg number of disagreements). I would also recommend applying some weight to the score. So instead of $1- \text{whatever}$, you have $1-W\cdot \text{whatever}$.

Comment: Because disagreements are rare, when they occur they can be given a higher weight. Exactly what weight is relevant would depend on your data set, expectations, tolerance, etc.

Comment: What are these annotations?

Comment: @PeterFlom For example, you are preparing a cat images detection dataset. You have a list of photos, and annotators will indicate 0 if not a cat image and 1 if it is.